# Taking Hadiyah after Taraweeh is permitted?

Tags: halal-haram, money, taraweeh

In our mosque, Imam had been ill for a few days in Ramadan. Then the mosque committee selected me as Imam for only the Taraweeh prayer. No contract were dealt there about money. I just agreed to be a Taraweeh Imam in that mosque. After 27th Taraweeh, afer finishing Quran in Taraweeh prayer, the mosque committee wanted to give me Hadiya. Now **Is taking this hadiya like taking money by reciting Quran in Taraweeh prayer(so it is Haram to take) or this can be treated as general/common/usual hadiya(so it is Halal to take and use)?**

Comment: I suppose you can estimate it better than anybody. I don't know how anyone else than you can qualify the Hadiya ... I mean whether it was such or a payment.

Answer (score 2):

Since it was the Sunnah of the prophet () to accept gifts and refuse sadaqh, there's no harm in accepting a gift from anybody.

The rule of thumb in Islam is that anybody can accept a gift as long as he didn't ask for it, be it an Imam, a teacher, a qari' teaching Qur'an etc..